# How to play audio that shipped with Ionic2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an app where I need to put some audio files in the `/src/assets` folder and play them when a button is tapped.

I used Native Media object as follows:

```
import { MediaPlugin, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public media: MediaPlugin) {

  }

listenAudio() {
    const onStatusUpdate = (status) => console.log(status);
    this.media.create('assets/audio/sample.mp3', onStatusUpdate)
        file.play();
      })

  }
```

the `listenAudio()` function will be called when the button is tapped.

The audio simply does not play!!

Any reason ?

Comment: maybe the path is incorrrect.. try '../assets/audio/sample.mp3'

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same problem yesterday (just getting started with Ionic). After some trial and error, I finally got the following to work with the MP3 file saved in `src/assets/mp3/sample.mp3`:

```
let filepath: string = 'assets/mp3/sample.mp3';

// The filepath needs to be a URL for Android
if(this.platform.is('android')) {
  filepath = 'file:///android_asset/www/assets/mp3/sample.mp3';
}

this.media.create(filepath, onStatusUpdate).then((file: MediaObject)) => {
  file.play();
})
.catch(e => console.log('Error opening media file', e));
```

A couple of other issues I've found:

- If the audio file's path is incorrect (e.g. the audio file doesn't exist), I would expect the `catch()` block to run, but the code fails silently.
- The audio file doesn't play on the Android emulator (running Android 6.0), but does work on a real device.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. It was the solution I was looking for.